# Successful query response won't display in Postman..?

Tags: node.js, postman, bookshelf.js

I am working on a GET request, and I am having issues with getting my response to appear when using Postman. It prints to the console appropriately, but I would like to get it working in Postman if possible.

Technologies: Node, Express, Knex, Bookshelf.

tester.js (the model):

```
const bookshelf = require('../bookshelf');
const Tester = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName: 'tester_info'
});
module.exports = Tester;
```

route.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/controller.js');
router.get('/testurl', controller.getData);
```

controller.js:

```
const Tester = require('../models/tester');
function getData(req, res) {
   new Tester({name: 'John'}).fetch()
      .then(results => {
         res.send(results); // Also tried res.send(results.toJSON())
      }).catch(function(error) {
         res.send('Could not retrieve data.');
      });
}
module.exports = getData;
```

Postman output is currently just `{}`, but the status is 200 and the name appears in terminal when using `console.log(results.get('last_name'))` with the controller code.

Edit -
Output of results using console.log():

```
ModelBase {
  attributes: [Object: null prototype] {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe'
  },
  _previousAttributes: {
    first_name: 'John',
    last_name: 'Doe'
  },
  changed: [Object: null prototype] {},
  relations: {},
  cid: 'c1',
  _knex: null
}
```

I'm guessing it's an easy fix, but I am stumped after staring at this so long. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `res.json(results)`, if that does not work can you give the value of `results`?

Comment: @onuriltan I just realized I mistyped some things. ```{name: 'first_name'}``` has been changed to ```{name: 'John'}```, and ```console.log(results.get('first_name')``` has been changed to ```console.log(results.get('last_name')```. Sorry for any confusion. The suggestion for ```res.json(results)``` returned ```{}```. I'll include the results output in an edit above.

Comment: Can you give the output of `results.toJSON()` and also try `res.json(results.toJSON())`? toJSON should return a json object and res.json should add header `application/json` as content type of the response so you will be able to see the response in postman

Comment: @onuriltan The output of ```console.log(results.toJSON())``` is ```{}```. Using ```res.json(results.toJSON())```, I get ```{}``` in Postman.

Comment: Shouldn't you search for `{firstName: 'John'}` instead of `{name: 'John'}`?

Comment: I also see you use modelbase, can you also try modelbase methods like `Tester.findAll({ firstName: 'John' }, { require: true });`

Answer (score 0):

Use `res.json(results)`, instead of `res.send(results)`;